# @Embeddable is Foo.class' PK and Bar.class' FK to Foo.class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.2

I am trying to define JPA layer over a db I cannot redesign.
That layer contains a OneToMany relationship where the Many part has a foreign key consisting of the same 2 fields that the one part has as primary key.

```
@Embeddable
public class FooKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="foo_id")
    private String id;
    private String secondaryId;
}

public class Foo {
   @EmbeddedId
   private FooKey id;
   (...)
}

public class Bar {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    (...)

    //@Embedded FooKey fooKey;
    @ManyToOne
    private Foo foo;
   }
```

How can I solve this? I am getting the error `@Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by mean of:

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn (name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "foo_id"),
            @JoinColumn (name = "secondary_id", referencedColumnName = "secondary_id")
  })
  private Foo foo;
```

Although if anyone has a more elegant solution, I will accept it